# Questions about pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have an API for a function that gets `***int` as a parameter.

```
void APIfunc(int ***in_variable)
```

I write a new function and I have to use this `APIfunc`.

I want to use a local `int` in my function (and not `int***`) but I want to pass it to the `APIfunc` (that gets `int****`).

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure this is pointer to pointer to pointer to int as your wish to use a local int as parameter suggests? Or could it be sth. like ponter to int[][]?

Comment: Too vague, not enough information on what are you up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you call the function depends on whether it allocated memory or it just accesses the memory.

**Case: It Allocates Memory**

Since it does not seem to have arguments about the size of objects, the type of objects, number of objects, does it assume them? In that case, you need to call it thus:

```
int** in_variable;
APIfunc(&in_variable);
```

**Case: It Just Accesses The Memory**

You must have the data allocated somewhere. You need to call it thus:

```
int*** in_variable;
// Allocate memory and fill up the data
// ...

// Call the function
APIfunc(in_variable);
```

Hope that clarifies a few things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Relying only on syntax,

```
int foo;
int *bar = &foo;
int **bar2 = &bar;
APIfunc(&bar2);
```

However, just read function documentation. If is unbelievable that it takes so deep pointer chain just to modify single value; must be something much more sophisticated.